# Android : Smooth Progress Bar with both decrements and increments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-progressbar

I want a progress bar that decreases with time(sort of countdown timer) and increases if the user hits the correct button . A sample can be found out at the link: [Rainbow Rex](http://rainbowrex.herokuapp.com/). This is the kind of progress bar that I am looking for.

I have tried AsyncTask and threads and they do work for a smooth progress bar but cannot increase the progress on correct user click. Please help!
        public class ShowCustomProgressBarAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    int myProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        myProgress = 50;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while(myProgress>=0){
            myProgress--;
            publishProgress(myProgress);
            SystemClock.sleep(200);
        }
        return null;
    }

  @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        customProgress.setProgress(values[0]);
   }
```

Comment: maybe you should post up your code to get started...

Comment: @Saurav why don't you use an `ObjectAnimator` to change/animate the progress between the different progress values - `ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 40, 60).setDuration(2000).start();`

Comment: Already tried that. Gives an error that animator cannot be used inside a thread.